# How to put a widget in a page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress and I am trying to figure out how menus relate to widgets. Is there a way I can add a widget to a page? Not on the side bar but in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, I'm afraid :( However, a 'sidebar' in WordPress can be any container in your website. It does not necessarily need to be on the side of your page. You can use [register_sidebar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/register_sidebar) in your functions.php file to create a new sidebar, then simply display the widgets in your new sidebar with [dynamic_sidebar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/dynamic_sidebar). It's your CSS that places the sidebar on the side of your page. If you look at it that way, you can instead use CSS to make a horizontal 'sidebar' for instance. The name 'sidebar' will most likely change at some point in the future to better reflect that.

Comment: hmmm I see, So I can add a (side bar) that is simply a bar anyware in my template and add there any widgets I need, and I can also relate that sidebar to a spesific page?

Comment: Yep. For example, you could have a horizontal row 'sidebar' of widgets on the homepage and a vertical column 'sidebar' on interior pages.. just different positioning with CSS. If your site is small enough, you can simply make a bunch of sidebars (one per page). If the site is larger, you can use a few sidebars and a plugin like Widget Logic to set which plugins show on which pages. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/